# Branch & Bound Knapsack Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, knapsack-problem, branch-and-bound

I have to implement an algorithm for the best first, branch and bound knapsack problem. However, my algorithm doesn't give me the right answer. My KWF2 function to find out the upper bound works, but calling knapsack(0,0,0,n) gives me a very off answer of 5, when it should be 90.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int C;
int *w;
int *p;
int maxprofit;
int *include;
int *bestset;
float *x;
int numbest;

void knapsack(int i, int weight, int profit, int n);
int promising(int i, int weight, int profit, int n);
int KWF2(int i, int weight, int profit, int n);

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    FILE *in = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    int n;
    fscanf(in,"%d,%d\n",&n,&C);
    //scan in items
    w = malloc(sizeof(int)*(n+1));
    p = malloc(sizeof(int)*(n+1));
    include = malloc(sizeof(int)*(n+1));
    bestset = malloc(sizeof(int)*(n+1));
    x = malloc(sizeof(float) * (n+1));

    float ratio[n+1];

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        fscanf(in,"%d,%d\n",&w[i+1],&p[i+1]);
        ratio[i+1] = (float)p[i+1] / (float)w[i+1];
    }

    //sort in decreasing p/w ratio
    int temp_w,temp_p;
    float temp_r;
    int j;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        for(j = i + 1; j <= n; j++){
            if(ratio[i] < ratio[j]){
                temp_w = w[i];
                temp_p = p[i];
                temp_r = ratio[i];

                w[i] = w[j];
                p[i] = p[j];
                ratio[i] = ratio[j];

                w[j] = temp_w;
                p[j] = temp_p;
                ratio[j] = temp_r;
            }
        }
    }

    //printf("bound of 1 = %d",KWF2(1,2,40,n));
    maxprofit = 0;
    numbest = 0;
    //printf("node 2 bound = %d\n",KWF2(2,2,40,n));
    knapsack(0,0,0,n);
    //printf("maxprofit = %d\n",maxprofit);

    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}

void knapsack(int i, int weight, int profit, int n){
    printf("profit= %d\n",profit);
    if(weight <= C && profit > maxprofit){
        maxprofit = profit;
        numbest = i;
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j <= n; j++){
            bestset[i] = include[i];
        }
    }
    if(promising(i,weight,profit,n)){
        include[i+1] = 1;
        knapsack(i+1,profit+p[i+1],weight + w[i+1],n);
        include[i+1] = 0;
        knapsack(i+1,profit,weight, n);
    }
}

int promising(int i, int weight, int profit, int n){

    if(weight >= C) return 0;
    int bound = KWF2(i+1,weight,profit,n);
    //printf("bound = %d\n",bound);
    if(bound > maxprofit) {
        //printf("bound = %d\n",bound);
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}

int KWF2(int i, int weight, int profit, int n){

    int weight1 = weight;
    int bound = profit;
    int j;

    for(j = i; j <= n; j++){
        x[j] = 0;
    }

    while(weight1 < C && (i <= n)){

        if(weight1 + w[i] <= C){
            x[i] = 1;
            weight1 += w[i];
            bound += p[i];
        }
        else{
            x[i] = ((float)C-(float)weight1)/(float)w[i];
            weight1 = C;
            bound = bound + p[i] * x[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    //printf("profit = %d\n",profit);
    //printf("%d\n",profit+p[2]+(C-7)*p[3]/w[3]);
    return bound;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any static variables or data passed by pointers. All is automatic variables. What do you mean? What is your problem? Where does the code fail?

Comment: when calling any of the memory allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when coding variable names, use names that are meaningful in the current context.  In general, variable names should indicate contents or usage (or better, both).  single character variable names are meaningless, though common usage is that i,k,j are used for indexes.

Comment: when accessing any string beyond `argv[0]`, always, first, check the contents of `argc` to assure the command line parameter actually exists.  if the expected command line parameter does not exist, then output a USAGE message to `stderr` (typically via a `fprintf( stderr, ... )` statement then call: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: the token: `include` is a C language keyword.  It should never be used for a variable name.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, including `fscanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling the `fopen()` function, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror()` and then `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  2) it helps immensely to insert a key comment here and there to indicate either what is being tested or the meaning of the result of a prior test.

Comment: in general, for clarity, a function name should be an active verb followed by what the verb is acting upon.  Meaningless function names like: `KWF2` should be purposely avoided.

Comment: why skip array index 0 in each of the arrays in the posted code?